¿Cómo modificar masivamente registros de MYSQL con un valor duplicado?
La idea consiste en hacer que la columna DNI sea única y no nula (desconozco el por qué originalmente se hizo para que permitiera nulos y valores duplicados).
La idea es asignar el valor del ID (de forma temporal) a la columna DNI para aquellos registros cuyo DNI = NULL, esta parte es sencilla y una vez aplicado este cambio podré hacer que la columna no acepte más nulos.
UPDATE my_table
SET DNI = id
WHERE DNI is NULL;

Para el caso de valores duplicados, no sé cómo hacerlo:
Entiendo que haciendo esto, me devuelve los duplicados:
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY DNI
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

La idea sería modificar el valor actual de DNI a uno de los registros, asignándole "-" + ID.
Ejemplo:
ID, NOMBRE, DNI
1, CARLOS, 70707070
2, DAVID, 70707070

Debería quedar:
ID, NOMBRE, DNI
1, CARLOS, 70707070
2, DAVID, 70707070-2

Si me orientan cómo realizar esto o algo similar en MySQL, se los agradecería mucho. Lo que no puedo hacer es eliminar registros.
¿No es posible hacer algo así?
UPDATE my_table
SET DNI = CONCAT_WS('-', DNI, id)
WHERE DNIIN (SELECT DNI FROM my_table
    GROUP BY DNI HAVING count(*) > 1);


¿Cursores + actualizar el segundo registro en adelante por cada DNI con más de una coincidencia?

¿Cursores? serían tan amable de mostrar un ejemplo?

¿Que versión de mysql estas usando?

la versión es 10.6.18

De cuantos registros hablamos? A veces yo prefiero no optar por la opción más técnica. Aunque no has dado mayor información de las tablas y cuantos datos son y todo eso, yo optaría por algo más normal. Coges la data de la columna DNI con los ID asociados > los pones en un Excel > identificas los duplicados y los eliminas de la DB dejando uno > vuelves a coger data de esas dos columnas > cambias el ID por el DNI > Toda esa data en Excel la pegas en la columna DNI de la DB. Vuelvo y repito, desconozco la magnitud de tus datos pero a veces lo más "profesional" no siempre es la mejor solución.

hablamos de 7000 bd, el cambio lo aplicaré de forma masiva a todos. ¿Hay chance de que tengas otra idea jajaja? (ni idea de cuàntos registros por cada una de las 7000 bd)

7k de Bases de datos?????????  No, la verdad es que te conviene mejor hacer un proceso automático. Igual no pones lenguaje usado. Pero una vez poniéndonos a pensar podría llegar a salir algo. Yo iría paso a paso... Suerte, la necesitaras!

Jajajajaa muchas gracias! acabo de editar mi pregunta con un ejemplo de cómo me imaginaba solucionarlo ¿no es posible hacer algo así? aunque lo único es que se editarían todos los duplicados (si me ahorra tiempo, no me importaría). Pero no me funciona la consulta.

@Carlos ¿qué dificultad estás encontrando con la respuesta que te dieron?

La versión que mencionaste suena más bien a MariaDB, no a MySQL. Esto es un cursor.

7000 bd que quiere decir?? 7000 registros??? no es nada... cuantos tenes repetidos?? en cualquier lenguaje, con un query ordenado lo haces en un par de lineas mas alla de los querys...

7000 bd son 7000 bd, registros ni idea por cada una. En algunas sé que 0.

crear una tabla complica las cosas en mi caso. Encontré otra solución, la voy a publicar y obviamente agradecería sus comentarios al respecto.

7000 db? 7000 bases de datos??? o sea.. no se para quien estas trabajando.. pero yo trabajo para un lugar grande.. grandisimo.. y no tenemos 7000 bases de datos...

UPDATE my_table C1 JOIN 
  (SELECT dni FROM my_table 
   GROUP BY dni HAVING count(id) > 1) dup ON C1.dni = dup.dni 
SET C1.nif = CONCAT_WS('-', C1.dni, C1.id)

Fuente: última respuesta de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103941/how-to-update-a-column-of-all-duplicate-records-in-mysql
Entiendo que se modifican TODOS aquellos duplicados.

El concepto de "última respuesta" es relativo: las respuestas se pueden ordenar por mayor puntuación, fecha de modificación o fecha de creación.
